# Flutter: Error de Button Overflowed by pixeles

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito ayuda con esto al voltear el dispositivo en horizontal ocurre el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura del codigo:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

```
 return new Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: PrimaryColor,
      title: new Text('Registrar Vehiculo'),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 50, top: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width,
                              child: Text(
                                'Selecione marca',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, ...
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            AbsorbPointer(
                              absorbing: _isButtonDisabledmarca,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .width * .5,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(_valueMarca),
                                    //Valor a cambiar
                                    splashColor: Colors.black,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: PrimaryColor,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      MarksDeVheiculo();
                                    }
                                ),

                              ),
                            ),
                            //==============ICONOOOO
                          ],
                        ),

                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/icono_shell.png', width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                      ), //=====No va , icono de otra cosa
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                //--------------------------------First Mark
                Container(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: Text(
                                'Seleccione Modelo',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, ...
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            AbsorbPointer(
                              absorbing: _isButtonDisabledmodel,

                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .5,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(_valueModel),
                                    splashColor: Colors.black,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: _activatebutton1
                                        ? Colors.grey
                                        : PrimaryColor,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      cargarmodelos();
                                      ModelDeVheiculo();
                                      Modelosdecarro.clear();
                                    }
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                ),
                //--------------------------------Second Model
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 10),
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width,
                              child: Text(
                                'Selecione Año',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, ...
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            AbsorbPointer(
                              absorbing: _isButtonDisabledyear,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .width * .5,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(_valueYear),
                                    splashColor: Colors.black,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: _activatebutton2
                                        ? Colors.grey
                                        : PrimaryColor,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      cargaryears();
                                      YearsVehiculo();
                                      Yearsdecarros.clear();
                                    }
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                Container(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 10),
                              width: MediaQuery
                                  .of(context)
                                  .size
                                  .width,
                              child: Text(
                                'Litros De combustible',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, ...
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 20.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            AbsorbPointer(
                              absorbing: _isButtonDisabledcombustible,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .width * .5,
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(_valueCombustible),
                                    splashColor: Colors.black,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: _activatebutton3
                                        ? Colors.grey
                                        : PrimaryColor,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      CargarCombustible();
                                      ConbustibleVheiculo();
                                      Combustibledecarros.clear();
                                    }
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                      // Image.asset('assets/images/icono_gas.png',width: 80,height: 110,),
                ),
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 30.0, top: 50.0, right: 0.0),
                    child:AbsorbPointer(
                      absorbing:_isButtonDisabledSave,
                      child:  SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                          color:_activatesave ? Colors.grey : PrimaryColor,
                          elevation: 5.0,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          splashColor: Colors.black,

                          onPressed: () async {  },
                          child: Center(
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text('Guardar Vehiculo',)

                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: Podrías agregar el código en lugar de la segunda imagen, para poder hacer las correcciones

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue

Comment: hmm lo acabo de probar y funciona bien, no me sale ningún error de overflow, que versión de flutter tienes?  en que emulador estas probando?  yo lo probé en el simulador de iOS

Comment: Tengo un emulador de android de AStudio, el nexxus 5 tengo la version 1.2

Comment: declaraste algo mas? en el manifest o en alguna clase dart para forzar la orientación ?

Comment: no, solo ocurre cuando el dispostivo esta en horizontal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes agregar `SingleChildScrollView` como wrapper del `Column` , quedaría así :

```
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 50, top: 10),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       Container(
                         child: Row(
                         ....
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si sirvió, eres un crack!!

Comment: no hay de que, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada